# Code keeps giving me "you lose" even though my guess is equal to random number

Tags: javascript

Kindly Check. This code keeps giving me "you lose" even tho my "guess" is equal to targetNum.

```js
let maximum = prompt("Tell us your maximum number");
const targetNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * maximum) + 1
console.log(targetNum)
let guess = prompt("Enter your first guess!");
if (guess === targetNum) {
  console.log("you win")
} else {
  console.log("you lose")
}
```

Comment: `===` will also compare the types. You're comparing a number with a string.

Comment: It's because `prompt` returns strings, and you're comparing them to a number. Convert the value returned by `prompt` a number first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`guess === targetNum`

You are using the strict equality operator, which is a good practice. It compares types and values. It does not do conversions.

Your problem is that `prompt()` returns a string and  and you are comparing it to a number. Try casting it to a number like this `const guess = Number(prompt('Enter your first guess!'))`.

You can read more about type casting here:

https://medium.com/swlh/typecasting-and-coercion-in-javascript-f0d59b0a86db
https://dev.to/antonmelnyk/understanding-javascript-type-conversions-43n

You can read more about the `prompt()` here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Answer (score 3):

That is because [`prompt()` returns a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt#return_value), not a number, while `targetNum` returns a number. A strict comparison of these two will always return false.

The solution is to ensure you convert `guess` into a number prior to comparison. You can use the [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) to do so:

```js
let maximum = prompt("Tell us your maximum number");
const targetNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * maximum) + 1
let guess = +prompt("Enter your first guess!");

if (guess === targetNum) {
  console.log("you win")
} else {
  console.log("you lose")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple error

> if (guess === targetNum) {

the syntax is wrong, a single `=` is to assign something to another thing, two `==` is to check if they are same, `===` three is for checking if they are of the same type as well as the values.

to convert the two to the same type, we can use the Number() Method as follows:

```
let maximum = prompt("Tell us your maximum number");
const targetNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * maximum) + 1
console.log(targetNum)
let guess = Number(prompt("Enter your first guess!"));
if (guess == targetNum) {
  console.log("you win")
} else {
  console.log("you lose")
}
```

Comment: Even if it works, it is usually a good idea to convert the types to match and use "===".

Answer (score 0):

"==" compares two data irrespective of datatype and "===" compares two data along with datatype.

your first variable datatype is number and second variable datatype is string.

use "==" operator instead of "==="